# Passing a value to a function returns null - vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display specific json information. Each Main category has its own Json file, which consists of *sub-categories*. Currently I am able to display the whole json file, but now I am trying to write a function which would display just the `clicked` *sub-categorie*.

I am trying to achieve this by binding event listeners to the sub-category menu buttons. The HTML structure:

```
Main category 1 (wrapper)
   Main button (id - category)
   Sub button 1(id - subcategory) (class="sub-sub")
   Sub button 2(id - subcategory) (class="sub-sub")
   etc
Main category 2 (wrapper)
   Main button (id - category)
   Sub button 1(id - subcategory) (class="sub-sub")
   Sub button 2(id - subcategory) (class="sub-sub")
   etc
```

The idea is, that when you click on the subcategory button, it returns to the wrapper (`parentNode`) and then gets the `id` of the `firstChild` ie. Main button. The correct json file should then be retrieved, but only show the desired category.

I haven't actually gotten that far. I am currently getting an error : `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Let me point out that I have tried to wrap everything into an self executing function and javascript is appended at the end of the document.

The error is pointing at: `let main_category = document.getElementById(clicked_sub_id).parentNode.firstChild(this.id);` ... so `clicked_sub_id` is null.

Why and how could I correct this.

Thank you for your help.

```
var subsub = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-sub");
var sub_btn = Array.from(subsub);
for (var i = 0; i < sub_btn.length; i++){
    sub_btn[i].addEventListener("click", SubAjax(this.id));
}

function SubAjax(clicked_sub_id){
    let main_category = document.getElementById(clicked_sub_id).parentNode.firstChild(this.id);
    RunAjax(main_category, this.id);
}

<div class="col-12 sub-main">
    <div class="first" id="box" value="box">
        <div>
            Box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-sub" id="b_small" value="b_small">
        <div>
            Small Box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-sub" id="b_medium" value="b_medium">
        <div>
            Medium Box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-sub" id="b_large" value="b_large">
        <div>
            Large Box
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.addEventListener` wants a function. However, you're calling a function and then giving `.addEventListener` the results of that call. See [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [simple example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#add_a_simple_listener) there.

Comment: thank you. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
var subsub = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-sub");
var sub_btn = Array.from(subsub);
for (var i = 0; i < sub_btn.length; i++){
    sub_btn[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) { SubAjax(e.target.id} ); //changed
}

function SubAjax(clicked_sub_id){
    let main_category = document.getElementById(clicked_sub_id).parentNode.firstElementChild.id; //changed
    RunAjax(main_category, this.id);
}
```